# Splitting a list in which figures vary from negative to positive

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

Consider the following list:

```
data={4078, 256, -1266, -388, 1290, 1368, 1446, 1524, 2};
```

I would like to split any kind of such list always, when figures turn form negative to positive. In the case of `data` the result would be:

```
{{4078, 256, -1266, -388},{ 1290, 1368, 1446, 1524, 2}}
```

I tried it with

```
Split[%, #2>0 && #1<0 &]
```

but I got:

```
{{4078}, {256}, {-1266}, {-388, 1290}, {1368}, {1446}, {1524}, {2}}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
Split[data, Not[#2>0 && #1<0] &]
```

Note that `Split[list, test]` splits `list` between two elements when `test` *fails*. In this case you want to to split the list iff `#2>0 && #1<0 &[e1, e2] == True` which is equivalent to `Not[#2>0 && #1<0]&[e1, e2] == False`.

Comment: Heike, you are indeed a great help! :)

Answer (score 9):

Probably the tersest way to write it

```
Split[data, ! #1 < 0 < #2 &]
```

Answer (score 8):

Alternately:

```
In[277]:= Split[data, Sign[{##}] != {-1, 1} &]

Out[277]= {{4078, 256, -1266, -388}, {1290, 1368, 1446, 1524, 2}}

In[276]:= Split[data, GreaterEqual @@ Sign[{##}] &]

Out[276]= {{4078, 256, -1266, -388}, {1290, 1368, 1446, 1524, 2}}
```