# Splitting a list using SplitBy, by comparing adjacent elements

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose that I have the following list called `mylist`:

```
mylist = {80.2, 80.3, 80.4, 327.6, 327.7, 327.8};
```

I would like to split `mylist` so that "runs of consecutive elements" are placed in the same sublist.  Here, I will define two "consecutive elements" as real numbers that differ by 0.1.  The second element can be either 0.1 greater than or 0.1 less than the first element, although in reality it makes more sense if the second element can only be 0.1 greater than the first element.  (In my actual application, `mylist` is a list of times [i.e., elapsed time], in seconds, for example.  My system is sampled every 0.1 seconds.  Time never moves backwards, at least in my world!)

So the result I would like is:

```
{{80.2, 80.3, 80.4}, {327.6, 327.7, 327.8}}
```

I am thinking that `SplitBy` would be appropriate for this application:

> `SplitBy[list, f]` splits *list* into sublists consisting of runs of successive elements that give the same value when *f* is applied.

However, in looking in the documentation, it is not clear to me how "adjacent elements" are defined.  In Mathematica 7, "More Information" says:

> `SplitBy` performs comparisons only on adjacent pairs elements.

Thus, what `f` do I use?  I have tried:

```
SplitBy[mylist, #[[2]] - #[[1]] == 0.1 &]
```

and

```
SplitBy[mylist, #2 - #1 == 0.1 &]
```

but neither work.  Does `SplitBy` define separate "slots" for the first and second element of a pair?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4191/5 (only the test function is different)

Comment: @rm-rf I think is not a dupe in the sense that while `SplitBy` is mentioned in the question, it *can not* be used for cases such as this, and this question (or rather answers to it) will emphasize that.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin You make a very good point.  I never understood (or realized, rather) the difference between `Split` and `SplitBy`, and your answer helps me to learn this.  Thanks.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Fair enough. I agree this is a useful question for why `SplitBy` cannot be used.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`SplitBy` is a wrong tool for the job here, because the condition you need couples adjacent elements in a way which can not be decoupled by applying some function to them.
I would use

```
Split[mylist, Chop[#2 - #1 -  0.1] == 0 &]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I execute `mylist = {80.2, 80.3, 80.4, 327.6, 327.7, 327.8};
SplitBy[mylist, Chop[#2 - #1 - 0.1] == 0 &]`, I get errors: `Function::slotn: Slot number 2 in Chop[#2-#1-0.1]==0& cannot be filled from (Chop[#2-#1-0.1]==0&)[80.2]` and so on for `80.3`, `80.4`, etc.  Do you have any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: @Andrew Please look carefully at the answer: I use `Split`, not `SplitBy`. `SplitBy` is a wrong tool for the job here, because the condition you need couples adjacent elements in a way which can not be decoupled by applying some function to them.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I completely missed that.  Your answer works perfectly!  Thanks!